# Change Css class of automatic validation - MVC2

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

`Html.ValidationFor` automatically applies `input-validation-error` css class to the target textbox. However the css is not mine to edit and I'm not allowed to change it (i.e. rename the sitebuild's `error` class to `input-validation-error`). Can I change the helper applies to the textbox somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a co-worker of mine solved the issue. HtmlHelper has private static fields (like `ValidationInputCssClassName`), which contain the classes as strings.

He called SetValue (by Reflection) on them...

Answer (score 0):

Those constants are [hardcoded](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528#266468) in the `HtmlHelper` class. You will have to write custom html helpers if you want to use different names. Probably would be a lot of work, much more than simply using those names in your CSS file.

Comment: I've already sent the email to the buyer asking to change the css. Hoping for some non-hard-headedness. I won't delete this answer in case anyone in the future wonders the same...